# Rip authentication from LDAP to local

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap, pam

We are taking a small portion of our network offline, and running a separate network using that portion. (By small portion I mean 2 servers, that will be connected to 30 odd boxes that aren't usually part of our network, and don't need to authenticate.)

I intend to create a VM on one of the servers to provide general user services, and IRC server, remote shell etc. And I would like the users to be able to use their usual server log in details.
Problem is the LDAP server that normally checks those details is not one of the servers.

So I need to somehow take their details off LDAP and put them on the server that is coming.

One suggestion I had was to set a LDAP server on the VM locally, and clone the LDAP database onto it (using something called slapcat).

Is this the best way? Or can I change the LDAP data into local authentication data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are running slapd (Open LDAP). Why not setting up a replication between the old and new server (e.g. with syncrepl) like EJP is suggesting?

Doing it this way, you won't have to "double" your data or copy it somewhere else.
Read more about syncrepl here:
http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html

Read more about creating a replication between two Open LDAP servers here:
http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin22/syncrepl.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run a local LDAP slave or proxy. You don't mention which LDAP server youre using but OpenLDAP supports a variety of replication models, one of which is certain to fit your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it only temporarily and you are using PAM you could use pam_ccreds or pam_sss to cache the authentication data that would be then also available when the LDAP server is offline.
If you are not you could use slapcat to backup and slapadd to restore it back again. I've asked something similar:
[ldap export and import](https://serverfault.com/questions/435261/ldap-export-and-import)