# ldap export and import

Tags: openldap

Is it possible to export all the data inside openldap for example using ldapsearch or some other tool to a (ldif?) file and then import everything on another server and put this in a script that would be run every day. So that I could use the other one as a backup when the first/master server is not available?

I have full access to the first/master server, but I can't modify it's configuration so I think I can't set up replication.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is it possible to export all the data inside openldap for example
>   using ldapsearch or some other tool to a (ldif?) file

Sure, it is possible. `slapcat/slapadd` is what you're looking for:

```
slapcat -f /path/to/the/slapd.conf -l backup.ldif
slapadd -v -c -l backup.ldif -f /path/to/the/slapd.conf
```

These are basically offline tools, you should stop `slapd` before proceeding. Maybe you also have to set/fix file permissions after restore.

Comment: Thanks, that looks just what I needed. I was just wondering if I can do it over and over - I mean do I have to purge the ldap database on the backup server before I do the slapadd command or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Yes. You must stop the `slapd` first, and delete old database `rm -fr /var/lib/ldap/*` then restore. If not, you'll get something like `Key/data pair already exists (-30996)`.

Comment: Ok, I will do that.

Comment: in OpenLDAP `2.4+` you probably want to use `slapcat -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d` for the new dynamic configuration operation.