# How to migrate users between two different versions of OpenLDAP?

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, slapd

I need to export and import users between Two different versions of OpenLDAP, Old openldap version is 2.42 and new one has version 2.44. Both the openldap servers are setup on Ubuntu.

In this answer [ldap export and import](https://serverfault.com/a/435271/447278) they have used slapcat/slapadd utilities, Will the same be applicable in my case as well? Because they have exported schema files as well.

I can export users using ldapsearch and add them on new openldap using ldapadd.
But when i export users using ldapsearch the userPassword attribute is in base64 encoded format how do i deal this that?

I just need to export users from older version of my openldap server please give suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict what you export with [`slapcat`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/slapcat) by using the **`-H`** flag. You are not required to export *everything*.

Alternatively export your users with ldapsearch with a similar filter.

[LDAP: backup with slapcat vs ldapsearch](https://serverfault.com/questions/577356/ldap-backup-with-slapcat-vs-ldapsearch)

Comment: But when I export users with ldapsearch the  userPassword attribute value is in base64 encoded format how to handle that? or it's fine?

Comment: That should be fine